# Ignore <script>-Tag while replace Keywords with Links

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I Want to Replace Keywords in a Text with a link. So I created this preg_replace:

```
$include = preg_replace('/(?!(?:[^<]+>|[^>]+<\/(span)><\/(a|option|h3)>|[^>]+<\/(a|option|h3|h4|h5|textarea|input|script)>))\b('.$key->key_word.')\b/is', '<a href="/'.$lang.'/'.$key->key_area.'/'.$key->key_page.'.html" title="'.$key->key_title.'" class="keylink">\\4</a>',$include,$limit,$count);
```

Now there is the problem that this regexp works within a JavaScript (...). How can I change it to solve this problem?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Lets dust off the old [Can't parse HTML with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: emm... The written Code works at this time. So I am able to parse the given Content. But now I want to ignore the Content between script and /script

Answer (score 0):

## Soapbox

We could craft a regex to match your specific case, but given this is HTML parsing and that your use case hints that any number of tags could be in there, you'd be best off using the DOM or using a product like [HTML Agility (free)](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

## However

Consider the following powershell example of a universal regex. In the example I am iterating over each matching text which would be outside any script tags. From here you could apply your string replacement to each matched group. It should be noted that this will break if inside the script you use a string that looks like open or closed `<script>` tags.

`(?:^|</script[^>]*>)(.*?)(?=<script\s|$)`

[image]

## Example

```
$Regex = '(?:^|</script[^>]*>)(.*?)(?=<script\s|$)'
$String = 'i wanna match a string contains<script src=value> is > that; bla ; bla is < this</script> match "bla" '

Write-Host start with 
write-host $String
Write-Host
Write-Host found
$Matches = @()
([regex]"(?i)$Regex").matches($String) | foreach {
    write-host "value at $($_.Groups[1].Index) = '$($_.Groups[1].Value)'"
    } # next match
```

## Yields

```
start with
i wanna match a string contains<script src=value> is > that; bla ; bla is < this</script> match "bla" 

found
value at 0 = 'i wanna match a string contains'
value at 89 = ' match "bla" '
```

Comment: Hey, which program did you use to get the diagram of the regex? Looks really nice! :)

Comment: @Igor: Thanks. I used debuggex.com which is a bit faster and more realtime then regexper.com. But they both to about the same thing. Really handy for seeing how a regex works.